# SignalR event not being received through dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-signalr

I am working on integrating SignalR into an error/exception logging package which is being consumed by an AspNetCore project.

The logging package offers 2 ways to log errors:

1. Manually through an `ICustomLogger` interface which can be injected, then calling `_customLogger.LogError(...)`
2. Automatically through a registered exception handler by registering `IApplicationBuilder.UseExceptionHandler` to construct an instance of the custom logger, then calling `.LogError(...)` similar to the above

To test this functionality, I have created 3 endpoints in a project which consumes this package:
`/UnhandledException`:

```
internal static async Task TestUnhandledException()
{
    //caught by the exception handler mentioned above
    //logs the error and a message is received in the in the front-end by signal r
    //no issues
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

`/SendMessage`:

```
public static async Task SendSignalRMessage(IHubContext<CustomLogger.SignalR.EventHub> hubContext)
{
    //uses the dependency-injected event hub from package
    //does not call any functions from CustomLogger
    //no issues
    await hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("NewEvent", "Hello");
}
```

`/ExplicitTest`:

```
internal static async Task Test(ICustomLogger logger)
{
    //relies on injected CustomLogger receiving an injected IHubContext<EventHub>
    //performs logging successfully but signalr message is not received in front-end
    //issues!
    var a = await logger.LogEventAsync(LogLevel.Info, "Manual event", "Is this message sent?");
}
```

The `EventHub` is registered in the consuming project's Program.cs through:

```
app.UseEndpoints(ep => ep.MapHub<EventHub>("/Events"));
```

The custom logging package consists of:

```
public class CustomLogger
{
    private readonly IHubContext<EventHub> hubContext;

    public EventLogger(IOptionsSnapshot<LoggerSettings> settings, IHubContext<EventHub> hubContext)
    {
        this.hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    //Snip boring code that does actual logging

    private async Task SendEventAsync(Event evt)
    {
        if (this.hubContext == null)
        {
            await this.LogEventAsync(LogLevel.Warning, "Configuration Error", "SignalR hub context is null");
            return;
        }

        var eventData = new NewEvent
        {
            EventId = evt.EventId,
            TimeStamp = evt.TimeStamp,
            Message = evt.Message,
        };

        try
        {
            await this.hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync(MessageType.NewEvent, eventData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await this.LogExceptionAsync(LogLevel.Warning, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, calling the function to manually log the data (in the non-working /ExplicitTest endpoint) requires a dependency-injected `ICustomLogger` from the dependency package, the constructor of which requires a dependency-injected `IHubContext<EventHub>`. The actual logging within the package will run successfully and on pausing the debugger, I can see that the injected `ICustomLogger` has an `IHubContext` with 1 active connection. No exception appears to be thrown when attempting to send a message to the connected clients, yet the message is not received.

Comment: Are you sure the parameter injection will be triggered for static methods? I don't know but it seems dubious.

Comment: Hi Hugo, could you kindly check the answer below, please let me know if it works for you, many thanks~

Answer (score 0):

After checking the issue, could you tell us why you are using `EventLogger` as a constructor in the `CustomLogger` class.

```
// Class Name
public class CustomLogger
{
    private readonly IHubContext<EventHub> hubContext;
    // <========= Here <==========
    // The name of the constructor should be same as CLASS NAME
    public EventLogger(IOptionsSnapshot<LoggerSettings> settings, IHubContext<EventHub> hubContext)
    {
        this.hubContext = hubContext;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Because of the lack of your EventLogger, I can't be sure that's the root cause, but you can set a breakpoint in SendEventAsync and see if the method is executed.

In my test environment, it works well. Please don't forget to add below codein your `Program.cs` file.

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR(); 
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICustomLogger, CustomLogger>();
```